# JSON Object not showing everything

Tags: android, json

I'm using Android Volley to fetch JSON objects from an API. I'm going to use this URL as a reference: https://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=la&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=puer&pretty=true

Basically, I'm trying to convert between Latin and English using this API. I'm having an issue where, when I fetch the JSON in my app, and display it using `toString()`, it doesn't show some content that I was able to see if I pulled it up in my browser. Here's what it looked like in my browser:

```
  {
  "result" : "ok",
  "tuc" : [ {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "boy",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meanings" : [ {
      "language" : "en",
      "text" : "male servant"
    }, {
      "language" : "en",
      "text" : "young male"
    }, {
      "language" : "en",
      "text" : "youth (1)"
    } ],
    "meaningId" : 5190805061708394514,
    "authors" : [ 89651 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "child",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meanings" : [ {
      "language" : "en",
      "text" : "a minor"
    } ],
    "meaningId" : -7607542873189716522,
    "authors" : [ 89651 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "lad",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meaningId" : -4906708417289394649,
    "authors" : [ 66257 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "young",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meanings" : [ {
      "language" : "en",
      "text" : "in the early part of life or growth"
    } ],
    "meaningId" : -3502972425310277951,
    "authors" : [ 83058 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "laddie",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meaningId" : 8881496802632467440,
    "authors" : [ 36 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "son",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meaningId" : -5777550766434985278,
    "authors" : [ 25115 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "teenager",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meanings" : [ {
      "language" : "en",
      "text" : "person aged between thirteen and nineteen"
    } ],
    "meaningId" : 3903113562290975250,
    "authors" : [ 83058 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "young man",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meaningId" : 8100655201654223005,
    "authors" : [ 1490 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "youth",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meanings" : [ {
      "language" : "en",
      "text" : "youth (1)"
    } ],
    "meaningId" : 3228296648002997345,
    "authors" : [ 92945 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "attendant",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meaningId" : -215343938140795468,
    "authors" : [ 66257 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "children",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meaningId" : -7262823696521965327,
    "authors" : [ 66257 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "kid",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meaningId" : 667611545945379095,
    "authors" : [ 13 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "little son",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meaningId" : 7069478616059810263,
    "authors" : [ 66257 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "male child",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meaningId" : -6364965082259980533,
    "authors" : [ 66257 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "servant",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meaningId" : 3306664352577272579,
    "authors" : [ 66257 ]
  }, {
    "phrase" : {
      "text" : "slave",
      "language" : "en"
    },
    "meaningId" : 3485776351359445593,
    "authors" : [ 66257 ]
  }, {
    "meanings" : [ {
      "language" : "en",
      "text" : "(in the plural) children"
    }, {
      "language" : "en",
      "text" : "boyhood (ex: <i>in puero</i>, &quot;in his boyhood&quot; or &quot;as a boy&quot;)"
    }, {
      "language" : "en",
      "text" : "a child"
    }, {
      "language" : "en",
      "text" : "a boy"
    }, {
      "language" : "en",
      "text" : "a male servant"
    }, {
      "language" : "en",
      "text" : "a bachelor"
    }, {
      "language" : "en",
      "text" : "vocative singular of puer"
    } ],
    "meaningId" : -1803685626071521178,
    "authors" : [ 1 ]
  } ],
  "phrase" : "puer",
  "from" : "la",
  "dest" : "en",
  "authors" : {
    "66257" : {
      "U" : "",
      "id" : 66257,
      "N" : "Charlton T. Lewis",
      "url" : "https://glosbe.com/source/66257"
    },
    "92945" : {
      "U" : "",
      "id" : 92945,
      "N" : "CLLD Concepticon",
      "url" : "https://glosbe.com/source/92945"
    },
    "1" : {
      "U" : "http://en.wiktionary.org",
      "id" : 1,
      "N" : "en.wiktionary.org",
      "url" : "https://glosbe.com/source/1"
    },
    "89651" : {
      "U" : "",
      "id" : 89651,
      "N" : "GlosbeWordalignmentRnD",
      "url" : "https://glosbe.com/source/89651"
    },
    "1490" : {
      "U" : "http://www.archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/words.exe",
      "id" : 1490,
      "N" : "Piotr Szelma",
      "url" : "https://glosbe.com/source/1490"
    },
    "83058" : {
      "U" : "",
      "id" : 83058,
      "N" : "Dbnary: Wiktionary as Linguistic Linked Open Data",
      "url" : "https://glosbe.com/source/83058"
    },
    "36" : {
      "U" : "http://freedict.org",
      "id" : 36,
      "N" : "freedict.org",
      "url" : "https://glosbe.com/source/36"
    },
    "25115" : {
      "U" : "",
      "id" : 25115,
      "N" : "GlTrav3",
      "url" : "https://glosbe.com/source/25115"
    },
    "13" : {
      "U" : "http://ro.wiktionary.org",
      "id" : 13,
      "N" : "ro.wiktionary.org",
      "url" : "https://glosbe.com/source/13"
    }
  }
}
```

When I pull it up in my app, it doesn't show the "phrase" portion. Here's the code that I used:

```
    RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getActivity().getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap
    Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
    mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
    mRequestQueue.start();

    String url = "https://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=la&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=" + e.getText().toString();

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {
                   Log.d("JSON", response.toString());
                    try
                    {
                        JSONArray arr = response.getJSONArray("tuc");
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject phrase = response.getJSONObject("phrase");
                        }
                        catch(JSONException e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Phrase not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        Log.d("JSON", arr.toString());
                        try
                        {
                            JSONArray arr2 = arr.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("meanings");
                            definition = arr2.getJSONObject(0).getString("text");
                            t.setText(definition);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Got stuff sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            JSONObject phrase = arr.getJSONObject(0);
                            definition = phrase.getString("text");
                            t.setText(definition);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Got stuff succesfully with exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                        Log.d("error", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    Log.d("Error", error.toString());
                }
            });

    MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using to parse it doesn't match the structure of the JSON.

"tuc" is an array, "phrase" and "meanings" are inside the objects in that array. Let's say you wanted to get just the first phrase:

```
JSONArray tuc = response.getJSONArray("tuc");
JSONObject phrase = tuc.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("phrase");
```

I think that's right but I don't have an Android project set up to test it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the code to parse your response in android:

```
                    try
                    {
                       JSONArray TUCarray = response.getJSONArray("tuc");
                        JsonObject phraseobject=TUCarray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("phrase");
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Phrase not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

Be careful when you are parsing the whole response because I could see that some objects of TUC array doesnt have sub object **phrase** eg:- Last object of the TUC array in the response of link you provided).